# refresh current cell automatically

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have added this function to jupyter config file as suggested here...

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1455

```
def stripWS(t):
    return '\n'.join([i.rstrip() for i in t.split('\n')])

def scrub_output_pre_save(model=None, **kwargs):
    """strip trailing space before saving"""
    if model['type'] == 'notebook':
        # only run on nbformat v4
        if model['content']['nbformat'] != 4:
            print("skipping WS stripping since `nbformat` != 4")
            return
        print("Stripping WS")
        for cell in model['content']['cells']:
            if cell['cell_type'] != 'code':
                continue
            cell['source'] = stripWS(cell['source'])
    elif model['type'] == 'file':
        if model['format'] == 'text':
            print("Stripping WS")
            model['content'] = stripWS(model['content'])

c.ContentsManager.pre_save_hook = scrub_output_pre_save
```

This works and removes extra space as advertised. I get this message at command prompt:

> [I 06:45:34.823 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
>
> Stripping WS

But I have a question:

Does the function runs only while saving notebook?

I guess so because I have to refresh the current tab to see that the extra space removed. Is there any way to auto-refresh the current cell after executing stripWS function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter extension nb_black will remove the extra space anywhere in the cell. Just use this command at the top of your notebook

> %load_ext nb_black

You may need to install the module using pip before using it.